# Delayed Overcurrent Protection

Tags: current, radio, delay, time

I trying to find a solution for a problem that I have with a system I am responsible for. The system runs on radio control, the problem we had is one of the radios got stuck on transmit and blocked up the whole system. The solution I came up with that I believe will solve the problem involves a time delayed overcurrent protection system. The closed I could find to what I was looking for is a definite time overcurrent relay, the only problem with these is that I can find one that will operate in the voltage and current range I am looking for.

The radio operates from a 12Vdc source and draws about 25W when transmitting. What I want to do is detect when the current goes over 1A and then wait about 1 minute and then cut power to radio. It most also reset if the current draw goes bellow 1A inside the 1 minute window.

I have come up with a very basic design so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0DZkA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If any one can think of a better solution please feel free. I am also looking for some through on what I can use to do the current detection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have given information on the radio, but nothing about the circuit that you will be measuring the current of. Is it also a 12v DC circuit? Is it a motor, or some other inductive load?

Comment: Some radios have this feature built-in. TX timeout. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

This is an electronics design forum. You could use a current sense resistor (shunt) and a current sense amplifier, and feed the output to a comparator. This will cover the current detection part of the circuit. Then it is just a matter of timing the excursion.

If you don't want to program a microcntroller, you could have the comparator output enable a digital timer (and reset the timer on falling edge). The timer can be set up to stop counting when it reaches a certain count (the timeout count).

If you don't mind programming a microcontroller, you could just feed the comparator output to an input on the microcontroller.

I do see a problem in your specification, however. Suppose the TX button is stuck. The timer starts counting, then at some point it cuts power to the radio. Now the current drops below 1A, and the timer resets, turning the radio back on. But the TX button is still stuck, so you immediately jump right back into the same problem.

Give it some thought.